# SFML package is failed to be installed due to "No .egg-info directory"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip

OS: Windows
I tried to run the command `pip install sfml` in the Terminal of Visual Studio Code, but the package wasn't install due to this:

```
Collecting sfml

  Using cached sfml-2.3.2.dev1.tar.gz (506 kB)

  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\{MyName}\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-38fg18k6
```

I should mention that this directory is not even existing, probably I should configure something or download an addition application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the [SFML](https://github.com/SFML/SFML) on github.

Here are three ways to download it:

1. You can get the latest official release on [SFML's website](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php).
2. You can also get the source code of the current development version from the [Git repository](https://github.com/SFML/SFML).
3. Alternatively, you can get the latest snapshot / artifact builds from the [artifacts storage](https://artifacts.sfml-dev.org/by-branch/master/).

The download on Pypi seems not to work.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the best solution for now. Could you please tell me how to quickly install it into the project?
I know there should be a command to take code from GitHub (like git ...). Then I can just run "import sfml", right?

Comment: @Petr Danilov Yes, use  `git clone` command to download the package from github.

Comment: Good evening, 
I tried to vote, but it's saying “you should have at least 15 reputation”. Sorry for not being able to vote your answer.